# Error in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

This is the code for my ExpandableList Activity

```
public class ExpenseEditorActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    MyDOA projedit = new MyDOA(ExpenseEditorActivity.this, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lv_Expenses = getExpandableListView();
        projedit.open();
        fillExpenseList();
        lv_Expenses.setAdapter(exp_adapter);
    }


    public  void fillExpenseList(){
        Cursor groupCursor=projedit.fetchGroup(SelectProjectActivity.sel_id);
        startManagingCursor(groupCursor);
        groupCursor.moveToFirst();
        exp_adapter=new MyExpandableListAdapter(groupCursor,this, R.layout.expense_list_expandableitem, R.layout.expense_list_item,new String[]{"expdate"}, new int[]{R.id.label_date},new String[]{"expname","expamount"},new int[]{R.id.label_eh,R.id.label_amount});

    }

    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
        public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,int groupLayout, 
                int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            Cursor childCursor= projedit.fetchChildren(SelectProjectActivity.sel_id, groupCursor.getString(0));            
            startManagingCursor(childCursor);
            childCursor.moveToFirst();
            return childCursor;
        }
    }
}
```

when activity is running fine as long as the expandablelistview is unexpanded(which is default) but when i click on a "group" to expand I get the following logcat errors

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 1 col -1 failed 
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method) 
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:412) 
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:108)
    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:437)
    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:192)
    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getItemId(ExpandableListConnector.java:421)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1992)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone please read into this and tell me why I'm getting these errors when I click any of the "groups.

Also if i set all groups as expanded in my code. I get the same errors as soon as the activity starts(obviously)

EDIT

```
public Cursor fetchChildren(int i,String date){
Cursor cursor=database.query("expense,expensehead", new String[]{"expense._id","expensehead.expname","expense.expamount","expensehead._id"},
"expense.project_id=\""+i+"\" and expensehead.project_id=\""+i+"\" and expense.exphead_id=expensehead._id and expense.expdate=\""+date+"\"", null, null, null, null);
return cursor;
}

public Cursor fetchGroup(int i){
Cursor cursor=database.query("expense", new String[]{"expdate"}, "project_id=\""+i+"\"",null, "expense.expdate", null, null);
return cursor;
}
```

My db looks like this

```
database.execSQL("create table project(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                "name text not null, " +
                "amount real not null, " +
                "startdate text not null, " +
                "enddate text not null, "+
                "avgbase integer not null);");
        database.execSQL("create table expensehead(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                "expname text not null, "+
                "project_id integer not null);");
        database.execSQL("create table expense(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                "expamount real not null, "+
                "expdate text not null, "+
                "exphead_id integer not null, "+
                "project_id integer not null);");
```

Comment: made the edit to include the fetch methods and create statements to the db because I cant seem to find any problem in the code. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [CursorTreeAdapter's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html)

> An adapter that exposes data from a series of Cursors to an
>   ExpandableListView widget. The top-level Cursor (that is given in the
>   constructor) exposes the groups, while subsequent Cursors returned
>   from getChildrenCursor(Cursor) expose children within a particular
>   group. The Cursors must include a column named "_id" or this class
>   will not work.

Correct me if I'm wrong but to make sure your `groupCursor` also has `_id` you need to put your group field in a separate table.

So I made a date table with an `_id` p.k. and the list is working fine now.